# 2d char array to string

Tags: c#, string, multidimensional-array

I want to use a 2d char array and have more than one string:

```
    char[,] str = new char[9,1000];
    int i=0;
    while (i < 9)
            {
                last[i] = str[i].ToString();
                i++;
            }
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: I believe we need more information and code. `While ( 9 < 9 )` ? Where/how is last[] declared? str[i] is only looking at one dimension.

Answer (score 2):

you are initializing your variable i = 9 so your while loop condition will never run

Answer (score 0):

```
string []last = new string[9];
for( int i=0; i<9; ++i )
{
  char []chars = new char[1000];
  for( int j=0; j<1000; j++ )
    chars[j] = str[i,j];
  last[i] = new string(chars);
}
```